# Error while running desktop app converter on VLC installer

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm getting E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED error while running the converter on VLC installer. I chose VLC because in one of the channel 9 videos, VLC was used as an example. I want to first try running converter on a sample exe installer before running it on an actual exe installer.

I even tried -Cleanup All and did the setup again but still the same error. Any idea how to trouble shoot and fix this issue? Below is the error message from converter :

---

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe> DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer C:\Project\vlc\vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe -InstallerArguments  "/S /L=1033" -Destination C:\Project\MSI\Output -PackageName "VLC" -Publisher "CN=VLC" -Version 0.0.0.1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Log file can be found in
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\logs\DesktopAppConverter.log
VERBOSE: Desktop App Converter
2.0.2.release_2017-04-20_15-32_d5d861e622cd5bd166242b726909575b22b31f27
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Checking Prerequisites

VERBOSE: Checking Windows Version to ensure it meets minimum requirements
VERBOSE: Minimum Windows Version requirement is met.
VERBOSE: Checking if Microsoft Windows 10 SDK is installed
VERBOSE: Checking Windows SDK version to ensure it meets minimum requirements.
VERBOSE: The installed Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.400 is supported
VERBOSE: Checking if MAKEAPPX.exe is available in the Microsoft Windows 10 SDK tools
VERBOSE: Checking if SIGNTOOL.exe is available in the Microsoft Windows 10 SDK tools
VERBOSE: Checking if MAKEPRI.exe is available in the Microsoft Windows 10 SDK tools
VERBOSE: Ensuring the provided Installer (C:\Project\vlc\vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe) exists
VERBOSE: Testing for required feature enabled...
VERBOSE: Target Image Version 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Required feature is enabled. Checking if reboot is required
VERBOSE: Target Image Version 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Required feature is enabled.
VERBOSE: Checking network config...
VERBOSE: Checking virtual network: "Windows Desktop App Converter Network"
VERBOSE: Using virtual network: "Windows Desktop App Converter Network"
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Initializing AppxManifest.xml

VERBOSE: Creating working directory structure at
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Identity.Name' to 'VLC'.
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Identity.Publisher' to 'CN=VLC'.
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Identity.Version' to '0.0.0.1'.
VERBOSE: No value provided for appx manifest property 'Package.Properties.PublisherDisplayName'.
Attempting to set it to the default value 'VLC'
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Properties.PublisherDisplayName' to
'VLC'.
VERBOSE: No value provided for appx manifest property 'Package.Properties.DisplayName'. Attempting
 to set it to the default value 'VLC'
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Properties.DisplayName' to 'VLC'.
VERBOSE: No value provided for appx manifest property
'Package.Applications.Application.VisualElement.Description'. Attempting to set it to the default
value 'VLC'
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property
'Package.Applications.Application.VisualElement.Description' to 'VLC'.
VERBOSE: No value provided for appx manifest property
'Package.Applications.Application.VisualElement.DisplayName'. Attempting to set it to the default
value 'VLC'
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property
'Package.Applications.Application.VisualElement.DisplayName' to 'VLC'.
VERBOSE: No value provided for appx manifest property 'Package.Applications.Application.Id'.
Attempting to set it to the default value 'VLC'
VERBOSE: Attempting to set appx manifest property 'Package.Applications.Application.Id' to 'VLC'.
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Validating Input

VERBOSE: Expanded base image(s) found at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images. Attempting to
choose the most recent one compatible with your version of Windows.
VERBOSE: Testing if expanded base image at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
 is compatible with your OS
VERBOSE: Your Windows version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine Windows version for expanded base image at
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine version from version file
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json if it exists
VERBOSE: Version found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
is: 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows version
10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: The expanded base image version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Ignoring revision numbers
VERBOSE: Expanded base image at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 IS
compatible with your OS
VERBOSE: Expanded base image with compatible Windows version found:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
VERBOSE: Using expanded base image: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
VERBOSE: Checking that the ExpandedBaseImage
'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393' is valid
VERBOSE: Testing if expanded base image at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
 is compatible with your OS
VERBOSE: Your Windows version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine Windows version for expanded base image at
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine version from version file
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json if it exists
VERBOSE: Version found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
is: 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows version
10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: The expanded base image version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Ignoring revision numbers
VERBOSE: Expanded base image at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 IS
compatible with your OS
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine Windows version for expanded base image at
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
VERBOSE: Attempting to determine version from version file
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json if it exists
VERBOSE: Version found in 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
is: 10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows version
10.0.14393.0
VERBOSE: Ensuring the provided Installer (C:\Project\vlc\vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe) exists
VERBOSE: Ensuring the provided Installer (C:\Project\vlc\vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe) exists
VERBOSE: Checking if Destination (C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC) exists
VERBOSE: C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC exists
VERBOSE: C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC exists but is not empty
VERBOSE: Moving files currently at 'C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC' to 'C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC.old3'
VERBOSE: Ensuring that this script has write permissions to C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC...
VERBOSE: Checking that installer is not sibling to working directory
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Setting up Conversion Environment

VERBOSE: Copying contents of C:\Project\vlc to
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\shared\installer to be shared with
isolated environment
VERBOSE: Copying KnownFolderDump.exe and its dependencies to
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\shared\dac\bin
VERBOSE: --------------------------------------------------


Running Installer in Isolated Environment

VERBOSE: No installer valid exit codes specified. Using defaults: 0
VERBOSE: Replace any occurence of <log_folder> in -InstallerArguments with C:\shared\logs
VERBOSE: Creating Isolated Environment
VERBOSE: Starting the Isolated Environment
VERBOSE: An error occurred running your installer in isolation
VERBOSE: Disposing of the Isolated Environment
VERBOSE: Moving any logs in
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\shared\logs to
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\logs
VERBOSE: Moving any dac output in
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\shared\dac\out to
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\output\dac
VERBOSE: Cleaning up by removing isolated environment shared folder
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\shared
VERBOSE: An error occurred converting your application. Here is the full error record:
VERBOSE:

PowerShell Error Record:
DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated
environment. See inner exception for more details.
PowerShell Stack Trace:
at RaiseUserException, C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\DACLogge
r.ps1: line 154
at Invoke-IsolatedInstall, C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\Isolated
EnvironmentOps.ps1: line 162
at <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1
: line 684
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1

Inner Exception[0]:
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: DesktopAppConverter : error
'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated environment. See inner exception
for more details. ---> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling
"Start" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One
or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function
call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned
because the timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
Inner Exception Stack Trace[0]
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)

Inner Exception[1]:
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Start" with "0"
argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors
occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned
error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned because the
timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
Inner Exception Stack Trace[1]
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)
   at
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
frame)

Inner Exception[2]:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. --->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned because the timeout period
expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call
returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned because
the timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()<---

Inner Exception Stack Trace[2]
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

Inner Exception[3]:
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. --->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned because the timeout period
expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
Inner Exception Stack Trace[3]
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode,
String result)
   at
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHc
s.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()

Inner Exception[4]:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800705B4): This operation returned because the
timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)
VERBOSE: The full error record is saved in the logs at
C:\DesktopAppConverter\9848b14c-013f-48d3-bc43-3b10b5987c58\logs
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppCo
nverter.ps1 : DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the
isolated environment. See inner exception for more details.
At line:1 char:1
+ &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConvert
   er.ps1

Output Paths:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CertPath
PackageFilesPath
PackagePath
LogFilesPath                   C:\Project\MSI\Output\VLC\logs


PS C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only other workaround would be to try the conversion on a different build or machine, you can also try using a VM.

Can you please reach out to us at converter@microsoft.com to help us investigate the error and debug.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure I will use a VM and try.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this [free alternative solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/02a95b59-9123-4360-be59-a3a60e39a1fd/desktop-converter-desktop-bridge-setup-converter-a-better-dac-with-gui?forum=wpdevelop#02a95b59-9123-4360-be59-a3a60e39a1fd) built by our company, that can help you convert the application much easier.

It is much easier to use, it has a GUI (no command line), built-in support for digital signing and allows you to customize the list of files that get inside your AppX.

Also, you can generate AppX packages for applications which do not (cannot) install silently.

It runs on Windows 7 too, not just Windows 10 (*recommended*).

Comment: Sure I will try this solution.. Thanks